# Loading a html file in to a richtextbox

Tags: c#

I want to load a html file into my richtextbox. What is the way to do it.?( i am creating a windows application)

Comment: Could you *please* take the time to learn the basic usage of this website? It seems as though all of your questions are equally confusing and badly formatted. Before asking more questions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Why do you want to load the file to a control like richtextbox?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to display web page in your windows forms?

Answer (score 1):

@Sgrassie and Konrad Rudolph: I wonder why you both underestimate the question. The answer is not in MSDN and will never be there. I faced the same issue **user162558** had here. I needed to display Html files inside RTF controls so I can add annotations and highlight methods. I don't want to just load Html file and display even the html tags!

However, what I do in such case, I use third party free software to convert Html files to RTF and then display them normally in RTF control. Simple, but, it's not simple to use those free third part software

Answer (score 0):

[RichTextBox.LoadFile Method (Stream, RichTextBoxStreamType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160332.aspx)

There are better (and more recommended) ways to do this for sure, but, simply:

```
private void loadFile(string file) 
{    
     this.richTextBox1.LoadFile(
            new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
            RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

I would recommend that you learn how to use MSDN, and look for information and tutorials on there, before asking a question on SO. Certainly for basic stuff like this.