# Make text bold between ^ and :

Tags: c#, winforms, string, delimiter

I'm doing a project in C# winform where I have a text with multiple items btw ^ and : that I need to make them bold.

Any help please?

Comment: Which UI controls are you using?

Comment: When you write `^` do you mean "start of line" (as in regular expressions) or do you mean a literal `^` character? Perhaps you could give an example text?

Comment: Use a RichTextBox and its SelectionFont property.

Answer (score 1):

Use controls which they can render html tags like `<b></b>` or `<i></i>`. A sample is RichTexTBox where you can have html tags inside your texts.

This may help you more : [Loading a HTML file into a RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519668/loading-a-html-file-in-to-a-richtextbox)

Comment: This would be the only way. Individual Winforms controls are either all bold or not at all.

Comment: Wish I could plus again for the extra help. :)

Comment: the ^ is a literal character. This is not a web, but a winform. Here an example text: ^Color swatch: blablabla. I need to put only the Color swatch in bold. I searched around for a way to user the ^ as a star and the : as an end of a string search but no lucky yet

Comment: You may need to make a further process on user input and change ^...: to <b>...</b> tags. If I understood correctly, a simple string process will make a html like string.